# Using cURL with NordVPN SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: curl, socks5-proxy, nordvpn

I am trying to use the cURL utility to fetch a web page through a NordVPN SOCKS5 proxy, but not having any luck. I would expect the following command line to work.

```bash
curl -v -x "socks5://<username>:<password>@se.socks.nordhold.net:1080" -4 http://google.com
```

However, this returns the following.

```
*   Trying 185.236.42.56:1080...
* SOCKS5 connect to IPv6 2a00:1450:4009:815::200e:80 (locally resolved)
* Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to google.com. (4)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (97) Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to google.com. (4)
```

Is there some special configuration I need for cURL to connect to a SOCKS5 proxy operated by NordVPN?

The customer support were able to tell me that

> We’ve changed the way for users to connect to socks5 to reduce the chances for socks5 from being used for malicious purposes such as web scans/proxying/credential stuffing attacks.

... but they could not offer any suggestions on how to use cURL. All I can say is that some other software seems to be able to use NordVPN SOCKS5 proxies without issue.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I've just figured out the problem myself. (As so often tends to happen shortly after spelling it out in full!) In case someone else searches for this, I thought I'd post what worked for me, rather than merely deleting the question.*

It turned out there were two issues at play here. The main one was that the version of cURL bundled with macOS (`/usr/bin/curl`) is *not built with SOCKS5 support*. I had the Homebrew version of cURL installed too, which does have SOCKS5 support, but it's "keg-only" (not symlinked somewhere the system can see). Putting Homebrew's version of cURL in my `PATH` meant that the IPv4 request of my original question then worked.

Furthermore, when I then used the `socks5h` URL scheme (instead of just `socks5`), IPv6 requests worked too. That ensures that hostname resolution is done remotely rather than locally.

```
curl -v -x "socks5h://<username>:<password>@se.socks.nordhold.net:1080" -L http://google.com
```